# Vuejs: distribute code across multiple components or everything into a single component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, code-organization

So I've played a lot with Vue, and now that my app has become large, I am having doubts about how to organize it.

I understand components and that they make sense when you need to re-use them many time on the same page, for example, a "custom select box" component, that will likely be needed in many places.

But what about components that will only have once instance? Example: a administration dashboard interface that has 3 areas: a sidebar with some navigation, a main area with stuff you can edit, based on what is selected in the navigation, another sidebar with stuff related to the main area. Do all these need to be separate components? Because I don't see any benefit of doing that if there is only one instance of each on the page. On the other side, if I stuff all the code in a single "app" component, I could simplify some of the code (less variables)

Comment: If you're using a tool like webpack, code splitting also means that you can lazy load components. This means your app is faster because it'll only load the components it needs at the time.

Answer (score 6):

Summary - typical reasons for using components:

1. Maintainability.
2. Rendering performance via component boundaries.
3. Loading performance via chunking.

If you find that using fewer components improves maintainability then that's fine. It may well be the correct design for your application.

Verbose version below.

---

The primary reason for using components is to improve maintainability.

Components that are reused in many places such as a select-box are obviously easier to maintain than repeating the same code over and over. However, it is worth considering why that is. It's not just that duplication makes it more difficult to make a change to all of the select-boxes. The other key benefit of using a component is that the extra level of abstraction can reduce mental overhead.

Let's say someone trying to maintain the code sees something like this (pseudo-code):

```html
<select-box :some-prop="blah">
  <select-box-option v-for="something" />
</select-box>
```

Immediately it's clear that this is a `select-box`. All the gory implementation details of the `select-box` are hidden away and we don't need to worry about them. By looking at the props, child components and events we can quickly deduce what data goes back-and-forth between the parent component and the `select-box`. This is just *separation of concerns*.

This benefit also applies to components that aren't reused. Let's take the sidebar example. We might see this in the template for our main component:

```html
<nav-sidebar @navigate="onNavigate" />
```

The component's name allows us to quickly identify it as the sidebar. If our current task doesn't involve the sidebar then we can just skip over that bit of the template. As the code has been moved off to a different file we have no difficulty establishing which bits of the code are part of the sidebar and which bits aren't.

In this example the `nav-sidebar` doesn't have any props and only has a single event. From that we can start to draw some conclusions about how these components interact. It would seem that the `nav-sidebar` doesn't need anything passed from the main component, it could quite happily live stand-alone. If we need to debug a problem with data flowing the other way we'd almost certainly start with `onNavigate`.

We couldn't start making deductions like these anything like as quickly if everything was mangled together into one, big component.

Of course it could be that our deductions are wrong. It could be that the `nav-sidebar` does some horrible things involving `$parent` to grab data from its parent component. However, that just illustrates why using such techniques is considered bad practice. Maintainable code should allow developers to jump to reasonable conclusions based on the abstractions that appear to be in place.

But it is possible to go too far the other way.

A good abstraction allows you to free up some mental capacity by hiding details behind a label. A poor abstraction adds mental overhead by hiding the code you want to see behind some indirection. Add to that the difficulty of naming things and the burden of extra glue code and you may well be better off just ditching the extra layers and keeping everything inline.

The other thing that can go wrong is splitting components up in the wrong way. Separating concerns requires clean partitions of those concerns. Chop things up slightly differently and you end up with a single concern being spread across multiple components and the resulting mess is typically worse than if you hadn't bothered splitting things up at all.

Vue allows you to split up your JavaScript code in a number of ways, components being just one. Separate `.js` files, plugins, filters, Vuex, mixins, etc.. There are several options available to you.

Templates, on the other hand, can only really be split up by using components. If you want to break a huge template down into more manageable chunks then components are really the only way to go.

This brings us to another key reason for using components.

A template is compiled down into a `render` function. When that `render` function is run it registers reactive dependencies, just like a computed property. If any of those dependencies changes it will trigger a re-render. That runs the whole `render` function again. Even if that doesn't result in any changes to the DOM it will require the generation of all the relevant VNodes and the diffing algorithm will need to check all of them.

Component boundaries are also rendering boundaries. Each component makes its own decision about whether or not to render based on whether its dependencies have changed.

So, taking the `nav-sidebar` example, let's say something changes in the `nav-sidebar` so that it needs a rendering update. If the `nav-sidebar` is a separate component then it just needs to run the template/`render` function for that component. If instead we bundle all the `nav-sidebar` code into the main template then we'll have to re-render everything.

Vue also has support for lazily loaded components as a way to reduce the initial load time of the page. The idea is that many applications have large sections, such as admin interfaces, that aren't relevant to most users. Rather than incurring the overhead of downloading all of those components you can split the components into chunks and download the chunks when they're needed. This is usually implemented via the Vue router configuration.

Chunking aside, the typical way to use the router is to have separate components for the different pages. While in theory it is possible to use the same component for all routes that is unlikely to lead to something more maintainable. I would add that the definition of *'page'* is a little fuzzy here but in most applications it's clear what constitutes a different page, resulting in a different component.

No tome on creating code monoliths would be complete without some mention of testing. Unit testing should be thought of as a form of reuse and a particularly extreme form at that. Tests have an unrelenting knack for exposing the mess of spaghetti that hides behind what you thought was a nice, clean design. I'm not going to pontificate on testing but suffice it to say that you won't be able to write unit tests unless you split things into suitable units.

Another key feature of a component is that it has its own set of properties. Its own `data` and its own computed properties. This sounds obvious but it gains significance when you consider looping via `v-for`.

```html
<div v-for="item in items">...</div>
```

The example above uses inline elements instead of components. Any state can only live on the parent. That state needs to be held for each loop item, so we may end up with multiple arrays holding different aspects of the state. Computed properties are similarly difficult to implement when working with loops. We typically end up using methods instead:

```html
<div v-for="item in items" :class="getClassesFor(item)">...</div>
```

Now consider the component version:

```html
<my-component v-for="item in items" :item="item" />
```

Each `my-component` can hold its own state. Let's say, for example, that `my-component` has expand/collapse functionality. That can now be stored in a local `data` property within each instance. Likewise each instance will have its own computed properties.

Arguably this is just reuse as the `v-for` creates multiple instances. However, given we're specifically introducing a new component just to provide a form of property scope, I think it warrants a special mention.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to have 3 types of components.

1. Reusable system component.  These are used for generic layouts, custom buttons, custom select box ...  They are meant to be reused multiple times in the code and be very versatile.
2. Page/View component.  The route usually routes to a specific component.   This component is some kind of assembly of multiple components.  The distinction allows to quickly identify the "page" of the application.
3. Logical division.  These are the hardest to find.  I tend to isolate things that are not related to each other.  For instance, a footer may not be reuse but a modification in the footer should concern only the footer.  Other examples are the navbar, the menu, each section of an admin.  These components should be reusable as much as possible but sometimes they will be specific.

Another example: A comment system.  A "comment" would be a component of type 3. A "comment thread" display would be another component of type 3 that use the "comment" component.  A page would exist for the subject of a comments thread and would be of type 2.
Note that each component of type 3 and 2 may use other components of other types.
If I want to change the display arrangement of the comment thread I only have to change the "comment thread" component.

Answer (score 0):

Vue components uses not only for re-use. You may split components into logical blocks. SPA for example. You can create grid based on vue components.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the reason why you need to split codes even it is used only once.*

> With hundreds or thousands of lines of code, it's no question that
>   splitting code in different files can help make it more manageable.
>   Although, this can quickly turn into a complicated mess if the
>   splitting isn't thought out beforehand.

The more you split codes, the clearer it becomes.

It does not only work for Vue JS but also works for almost programming languages.

Comment: "The more you split codes, the clearer it becomes." Citation needed.

Comment: There is no citation of that sentence. That is just my thought.